# Какие сигналы передавать в com-порт?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com-порт

1. Есть пошаговый двигатель, который управляется через манипулятор. Манипулятор принимает сигналы с компьютера. манипулятор подключается к компьютеру через ЮСБ, создается виртуальный ком порт.
2. Есть стандартная программа для общения компьютера и манипулятора(исходник закрыт).
3. Мне надо написать свою программу для общения(это будет частью многозадачной программы).
4. Я написал программу, которая открывает нужный ком порт и передает сигнал. Но есть проблема-я не могу понять какой формат хочет получить от меня программа. В документации сказано, что запуск двигателя определено командой MV.

   В ком порт я отправляю указатель на начало строки `char Command[]="MV"` (указатель приведен к типу `(void * ))`  и говорю ему отправить `2*sizeof(char)` информации.

> ```
> WriteFile(hCOM, (void * )Command, 2*sizeof(char), NULL, NULL );
> ```

Манипулятор считывает и отправляет назад ответ "*Ошибка приема по com порту*".

Как можно узнать какой сигнал он хочет получить?

http://electroprivod.ru/pdf/smsd-4.2.pdf - такой манипулятор

http://electroprivod.ru/pdf/smsd-42-pasp.pdf - тут паспорт, в котором сказано, какие команды надо подавать!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Елки палки возьмите **portMonitor** и посмотрите что в порт отправляет не ваша программа.

Потом посмотрите что отправляет ваша программа и сравнивайте где и что.

Comment: @savro, как мониторинг сделать?
как общаться с портом нашел. а мониторинг нет..

Comment: в меню смотрите, по моему Capture events, при этом сразу укажите какие порты мониторить.

Answer (score 0):

Очень невнимательно глянул на команды (по ссылке 2) и мне показалось, что в разделе 7 написано, что

сначала надо войти в режим ввода команд (команда LD), ввод команд надо завершать символом '*', а потом запустить введенные команды (командой ST1).

Возможно перед MV надо ввести скорость (SD) и/или ускорение (AL).

Вообще система команд (как они взаимосвязаны) "мутно" описана.